# R par set cannot be changed

Tags: r, par, r-base-graphics

I wonder how I can use the par set of no.readonly normally.For the following code,

```
par1 <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
set.seed(2015)
xx<-rnorm(100)
par(pch=17,col="red")
plot(xx)
```

[image]

```
par2 <- par(no.readonly=TRUE) # par2 pch=17,col='red'
par(pch=17,col="blue")
plot(xx)
```

[image]

```
par(par2)
plot(xx,main="why the color is black not red?") 
# why this time the col is default 'black'?
```

[image]

Could someone help me use par to set the color red as before? Why this time par is invalid for **col** but useful for **pch**?

Answer (score 0):

Your color is being overwritten by elements further in the list. For proof:

```
par(col = "blue")
par("col")
# [1] "blue"
par(fg = "red")
par("col")
# [1] "red"
```

(I'm not certain how many other oevr-riding elements there will be, but this is one that is likely impacting you.)

If you want to save/reuse `"col"` and `"pch"`, perhaps you should save them (and not the rest of the list).